# Using NProbability[] or Probability[] to work out the probability of 3 or more Heads from 4 coin tosses

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Is it possible to work out the probability of 3 or more Head from 4 coin tosses using the Probability or NProbability functions.

This is not a question about the trivial answer to this problem, it is more to get an understanding of how to solve this kind of problem with Mathematica using distributions.

So using 4 random variables from Distribution P

I was hoping something like this would do the trick, but it does not work. I get 0.

```
P = BernoulliDistribution[0.5];
vars = List[Distributed[a,P],Distributed[b,P],Distributed[c,P],Distributed[c,P]];
NProbability[Count[ {a,b,c,d}, 1] >= 3,  vars]
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two errors there: c declared twice and d never and using Count instead of Total.

Comment: Perhaps @Sjoerd is being too polite. After his modifications the OP's code works

Comment: Ha! So it does. The double declaration was a copy paste error to the site. Using Total instead of Count did the trick. Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not an expert using Mma for statistics here, but this seems to work:

```
l = TransformedDistribution[
       x + y + w + z, {x \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.5], 
                       y \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.5], 
                       z \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.5], 
                       w \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[0.5]}];

Table[NProbability[x > i, x \[Distributed] l], {i, -1, 4}]
(*
{1, 0.9375, 0.6875, 0.3125, 0.0625, 0.}
*)
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much! Explained it perfectly :)

Comment: At the mma tech conference right now with leonid. We don't have much tine doing anything else.

Comment: @Sjoerd Conference? With or without beer?

Comment: We had a social yesterday  where we could try the products of local brewery. Leonid made us miss the last bus back, but Daniel was kind enough to being us back safe.

Comment: Of course, we talked a lot about you and mr wizard. You were missed.

Comment: Lots of stuff under NDA. Can't tell much.

Comment: @Sjoerd Enjoy! And upload some photographs!

Answer (score 8):

```
In[10]:= Probability[a + b + c + d >= 3, vars]

Out[10]= 0.3125
```

Coin flipping is easier described with a BinomialDistribution:

```
In[12]:= Probability[m >= 3, m \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[4, 0.5]]

Out[12]= 0.3125
```

Comment: Yes that is a lot cleaner. I did notice the TransformedDistribution as suggested by belisarius gets evaluated to BinomialDistribution. Thankyou :)

Comment: @Bart I thought you did that on purpose because you wanted to know how to add random vars! Ha! Silly me.

Comment: @belisarius I did want to know how to add random vars and not just this yoy coin flip problem. So it being evaluated to a BinomialDist is just an interesting point in this particular case. What you provided is what really I wanted, a general understanding of how do these kinds of calculations. So you were spot on! :)